# Remove NULL from VARCHAR2 in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

There is a `VARCHAR2` type column in my database table for store `invoice_number`. and there is a query to get max `invoice_number` as below.

```
select max(invoice_number)  from invoice;
```

but there are no data in `invoice` table, above query return value as `null`. but in this case i need to replace this value to `0` instead of `null`. how could i do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using NVL:

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(invoice_number), '0')
```

Using the ANSI COALESCE:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(invoice_number), '0')
```

Using DECODE:

```
SELECT DECODE(MAX(invoice_number), NULL, '0')
```

Using the ANSI CASE:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN MAX(invoice_number) IS NULL THEN '0' 
         ELSE MAX(invoice_number) 
       END
```

#### Verdict

All work, I'd probably use NVL because COALESCE is ANSI but not known to necessarily work as fast as native alternatives.

Comment: Hehe, +1 for fixing the '0's ;)

Comment: @mootinator: I don't know what you mean :p

Comment: *Cough* must have been my imagination.

Comment: @mootinator: If the world ever crumbles, and small fiefdoms arise to govern the hungry masses, I shall be sure not to invade your barony.

Comment: In theory Coalesce is faster than Nvl as it only evaluates expressions that are required -- minimal in this case where the second expression is a constant, but quite appreciable in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use COALESCE
For instance:

```
select COALESCE(max(invoice_number),'0') from invoice;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select coalesce(max(invoice_number),0)
```

can also use Decode.

```
select decode(max(invoice_number),null, 0)
```

Comment: `coalesce` doesn't work. got error as `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`. but `decode` works.